# How to construct a basic_request<Tag> object (cpp-netlib)

Tags: cpp-netlib

I'm successfully using cpp-netlib (v0.11.0) and I'm developing some unit tests to test my HTTP server and handler function.

The handler function has the following required signature:

```
typedef boost::network::http::server<RequestHandler> HttpServerType; 

void operator()(const HttpServerType::request& request, HttpServerType::response& response)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is instantiate the request object so I can call the handler's function call operator. But I can't get it to compile.

In the above signature, `request` is a typedef for `basic_request<Tag>`,

which has a constructor which takes a reference to a `boost::network::uri::uri`.

The code below generates an error when compiled using clang 3.5.

```
boost::network::uri::uri url;

url << uri::scheme("http") << uri::host(host) << uri::port(port) << uri::path(path);

HttpServerType::request request(url);


No matching constructor for initialization of 'HttpServerType::request' (aka 'basic_request<boost::network::http::tags::http_server>');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

The template is specialised for the http_server tag.

```
template <>
struct basic_request<tags::http_async_server> :
not_quite_pod_request_base<tags::http_async_server> 
{};
```

and this only has a default ctor.

The following code does compile:

```
HttpServerType::request request;
request.destination.append("fred"); 
request.method.append("POST");
```